# PySpark Mongodb / java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame

Tags: mongodb, pyspark, connector, databricks

I'm trying to connect pyspark to MongoDB with this (running on Databricks) :

```
from pyspark import SparkConf, SparkContext
from pyspark.mllib.recommendation import ALS
from pyspark.sql import SQLContext
df = spark.read.format("com.mongodb.spark.sql.DefaultSource").load()
```

but I get this error

java.lang.NoClassDefFoundError: org/apache/spark/sql/DataFrame

I am using Spark 2.0 and Mongo-spark-connector 2.11 and defined spark.mongodb.input.uri and spark.mongodb.output.uri

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to make it work because I was using mongo-spark-connector_2.10-1.0.0 instead of mongo-spark-connector_2.10-2.0.0

Answer (score 0):

You are using `spark.read.format` before you defined `spark`

As you can see in the [Spark 2.1.0 documents](http://spark.apache.org/docs/2.1.0/api/python/pyspark.sql.html)

A SparkSession can be used create DataFrame, register DataFrame as tables, execute SQL over tables, cache tables, and read parquet files. To create a SparkSession, use the following builder pattern:

```
spark = SparkSession.builder \
.master("local") \
.appName("Word Count") \
.config("spark.some.config.option", "some-value") \
.getOrCreate()
```

Comment: actually I am using Databricks and I already have spark defined, I get '<pyspark.sql.session.SparkSession object at 0x7f25ac1ad6d0>' when I run print spark